# NGINX: Vue + Flask + Docker + Nginx, проблема со скачиванием файла через X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: vue.js, nginx, flask

Проект написан на Vue + Flask + Docker + Nginx.

Flask часть:

```
@app.route('/api/download-video', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*', headers=['content-type'])
def download_video():
    auth_key = request.json.get("auth_key", "")
    video_id = request.json.get("video_id", None)
    
    if not auth_key:
        abort(404)

    filepath = os.path.join(app.config["DOWNLOADED_VIDEO_FOLDER"], f"{video_id}_translated.mp4")

    # Check if the file exists
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        abort(404)

    response = make_response()
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={video_id}_translated.mp4'
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    app.logger.info(f'Real filepath: {filepath}')

    accel_redirect_path = f"/download-video/{video_id}_translated.mp4"
    app.logger.info(f'X-Accel-Redirect path: {accel_redirect_path}')
    response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = accel_redirect_path

    return response
```

Vue:

```
async downloadVideo({ commit }, videoId) {
    try {
        const sessionKey = sessionStorage.getItem("auth_key");
        if (!sessionKey) throw new Error("No session key available.");

        // const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/download-video/${videoId}`, {
        //     method: "GET",
        //     headers: {
        //         "Content-Type": "application/json",
        //         "Authorization": `Bearer ${sessionKey}`, 
        //     },
        // });
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/download-video`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ auth_key: sessionKey, video_id: videoId }),
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('response', response)
            const videoBlob = await response.blob();
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = url;
            a.download = `${videoId}_translated.mp4`;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        } else {
            console.error("Backend Error: ", response.statusText);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
},
```

Nginx config:

```
client_max_body_size 4G;
log_format timed_combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                          '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                          '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                          '$request_time $upstream_response_time';

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log timed_combined;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /download-video/ {
        internal;
        alias /app/uploaded_videos/video_video2text/;
        types {
            video/mp4   mp4;
        }
        default_type video/mp4;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }


    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend:5001;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
    }
}
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    image: *:backend-latest
    expose:
      - 5001
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - ./uploaded_videos:/app/uploaded_videos
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=production
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5001/ping" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - video_translator

  nginx:
    image: *:nginx-latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./proxy/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./uploaded_videos:/app/uploaded_videos
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    networks:
      - video_translator

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./proxy/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    networks:
      - video_translator

networks:
  video_translator:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
ARG VUE_APP_ENV
ENV VUE_APP_ENV=${VUE_APP_ENV}
COPY ./package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# development stage
FROM node:16-alpine as development-stage
WORKDIR /app
ENV VUE_APP_ENV=${VUE_APP_ENV}
COPY ./frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]

FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
ENV VUE_APP_ENV=${VUE_APP_ENV}
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Получается так, что на локалхосте когда пробую скачивать видео (через фронтэнд на вью), то nginx отдает его через пару секунд в браузер для скачивания. А когда запускаю на сервере в проде, то после нажатия на кнопку скачивания на фронэнде, в зависимости от размера файла, nginx может думать до получаса, а только потом отдавать файл браузеру для скачивания. Что самое херовое, что он даже не подает никаких признаков для юзера.

Может кто-то подскажет как решить это, чтобы nginx сразу отдавал на сервере файл для скачивания?

Comment: подозреваю что что-то не так в районе настроек сервера. Посмотрите на настройки sendfile/directio. https://serverfault.com/a/812737/211028